# VBA - Difficulty interrupting Application.OnTime

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficult interrupting a looped `Application.OnTime` command. I have a macro I want to periodically loop every 5 seconds (`CommandButton221`), but then I want to be able to cut the loop off by pressing `StopButton`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton221_Click()
    If StopMacro = True Then Exit Sub
    '[Code that I want looping, not relevant to the question]
    testup1
End Sub

Public Sub testup1()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "CommandButton221_Click", , True
End Sub

Public Sub StopButton_Click()
    StopMacro = True
End Sub
```

Any suggestions as how to achieve  this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Have you declared `StopMacro` at the module level?

Comment: @mwatters try the last macro in this page http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=61450

Comment: @GSerg Yes StopMacro has been declared as Boolean, apologies for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, a *slightly* different method, removing the schedule entirely when hitting the Stop button:

```
Public RunWhen As Double

Private Sub CommandButton221_Click()
    Application.StatusBar = Now()
    testup1
End Sub

Public Sub testup1()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "CommandButton221_Click", , True
End Sub

Public Sub StopButton_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:="CommandButton221_Click", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Make sure the code you have in 221 doesn't take more than 5 seconds to run!

Comment: Hi CLR, thank you for your comment. The code under 221 definitely takes less than 5 seconds. When I've tried your code the StopButton is still failing to do anything sadly, the CommandButton221 code keeps repeating. Also, I've no idea if this info is helpful but when I type MsgBox "Hi" after the StopButton's Application.OnTime.. the message box doesn't come up.

Comment: What if you put the 'Hi' before? If that still doesn't work then your button isn't firing the code.

Comment: You included the `Public Runwhen as Double` line?

Comment: Yes that's included

Comment: Really odd. It works for me (I just put some code in that writes the date and time to the status bar) running every 5 seconds and stops when the StopButton is clicked. Now I think about it though, your original code should work too. Perhaps there's something in your code block that is causing an issue. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Hi CLR, thank you for your time. Would you mind posting the code you have written that has the Stop Button work fine? I've just tried a new block of code with what you put above, and the same issue of it not stopping is still there.

Comment: I've altered my answer to how I tested this

Comment: Did you put all your above code in the Sheet or the Module? If I only put the code in the Sheet I get the error message "Cannot run the macro '..!CommandButton221_Click'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." I have made sure to enable all macros via the Trust Centre. But then when I copy paste CommandButton221 and testup into a module it does work.

Comment: If you're embedding these in the sheet, you'll need to include the sheet reference when calling the macro using `OnTime` like so:   `Application.OnTime RunWhen, "Sheet1.CommandButton221_Click", , True` - where `Sheet1` is the name of the tab.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the command DoEvents at the end of testup1() to yield control back to the O.S., which should allow the stop button event to occur. It is very easy for VBA to get stuck in loops with timers and/or heavy data processing and ignore other events.